# 405 Method Not Allowed in DocuSign SOAP API C# Client

Tags: c#, soap, docusignapi

I'm hoping that DocuSign will weigh in here. I'm using the page from the SOAP API Guide "Using DocuSign WSDL’s in the .Net Environment". I've used the CredentialsAPI to login successfully, and passed the baseURL to the constructor of the DSAPIServiceSoapClient. But I'm getting a 405 Method Not Allowed error on every call. I've tried it with the Integrator Key appended to the user name and without. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
CredentialSoapClient credsClient = new CredentialSoapClient();
LoginResult login = credsClient.Login(DSAPIUsername, DSAPIPassword, true);
string auth = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" + DSAPIUsername + "</Username>" +                            
              "<Password>" + DSAPIPassword + "</Password>" +
              "<IntegratorKey>" + DSIntegratorKey + "</IntegratorKey>" +
              "</DocuSignCredentials>";
_apiClient = new DSAPIServiceSoapClient("DSAPIServiceSoap", login.Accounts.First().BaseUrl);
_scope = new OperationContextScope(_apiClient.InnerChannel);
HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", auth);
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
```

Comment: You likely want to tunnel your requests through Fiddler so you can get actual direct messages and responses, the downside is fiddler is painful with SSL and i have to assume the docusign API requires HTTPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did as suggested, and I found the problem in my own code. When I looked at the error in Fiddler, the details showed "HTTP Verb used is not allowed". That's when I realized that I was POSTing to the base url, not to dsapi.asmx. That needs to be added when using the BaseURL from a login. Sorry Internets. User error.